# Checking for convergence of the series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(3^n x)}{2^n} $?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

i want to check for the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(3^n x)}{2^n} $.By applying ratio test i got $r=\lim_{n\to \infty}|\frac {4\cos^2(3^n x)-3}{2}|$.and the value of r changes from 1.5 to .5 .

Comment: What is the question? Are you applying the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem? It can be used only for power series. I would suggest using Weirstrass M-test.

Comment: i applied ratio test i.e.$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = r.$

Comment: This wont work for a series of functions. (The case you're dealing with).

Comment: then what should i apply Abel's test

Comment: As i suggested - You should apply M-test. This is the theorem XPenguen used in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a lookt at:$|\frac{cos(3^nx)}{2^n}|\le\frac{1}{2^n}$
The series $\sum_1^{\infty}{ \frac1{2^n}}$ converges....